# How To display the Profile Completeness In Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, progress-bar

I want to Display a progress bar for the User Profile Like [Naukri](http://www.naukri.com), in My ASP.Net Web Application Using Ajax Or JQuery. The bar shows the percentage of the profile completed.

Comment: Unfortunately, you haven't begun to provide enough information for us to help you. Firstly, what do you consider "completed"? non-empty? the form they're on has been submitted? Why would you need AJAX? Are values going to be updated by someone else and the user can see the change in the bar in real time? How are you storing profile information, What specifically can't you get working, etc.. If you can provide more information, we may be able to help

Comment: I want A Bar Like Profile Completeness In Nakari.... To User Registration Like Profile Completeness As 75%

Answer (score 1):

[Progress Bar](http://jurgens-nettuts-tutorial.s3.amazonaws.com/ASPNET.ProgressBar.pdf)
This tutorial has all the details you need for the progress bar to work!

Answer (score 0):

Well, nothing is like that available in Asp.net, What they do(according to me). checks for fields completed in your profile. i.e. some fields are mandatory so they show 60% completeness of your profile on their site. And if you upload your previous experiences they check it if user has filled then they move ahead progress of completeness to 80% and so on.

That's what according to my understanding and is a good way also to do it...

Comment: but in Progress bar How Can I fill The Bar With %

Comment: You can create a div and set a background picture for this div. And according to your criteria's set this picture's width and keep it expanding according to criteria filled up in your applications...and set its design as its a progress bar...